# Erro ''stack smashing detected'', porém não acho onde excedi a matriz

Tags: c

Após pesquisar sobre o erro, achei que tem alguma coisa relacionada a exceder os limites de
uma matriz. porém não encontrei onde ele possa estar em meu código. Bem o código roda como deveria rodar, pode não estar escrito do melhor modo, mas faz o que o enunciado pede. Se poderem me ajudar a descobrir o por quê desse erro, ficarei grato. Obrigado.

```
/*10) Usando a estrutura "atleta", do exercício anterior, escreva um programa que leia 
os dados de 5 atletas e os exiba por ordem de idade, do mais velho para o mais novo.*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct dados{
    char nome[50];
    char esporte[50];
    int idade;
    float altura;
}atleta;

int main(){
    atleta info[6];
    char aux[50];
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf(".....DADOS DO ATLETA.....\n");
        printf("NOME\t\t");
        fgets(info[i].nome, sizeof(info[i].nome), stdin);
        printf("ESPORTE\t\t");
        fgets(info[i].esporte, sizeof(info[i].esporte), stdin);
        printf("IDADE\t\t");
        fgets(aux, sizeof(aux), stdin);
        info[i].idade = atoi(aux);
        printf("ALTURA\t\t");
        fgets(aux, sizeof(aux), stdin);
        info[i].altura = atoi(aux);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for(j = i+1; j < 5; j++){
            if(info[i].idade < info[j].idade){
                info[6] = info[i];
                info[i] = info[j];
                info[j] = info[6];
            }
        }
    }

    printf("...ORDEM DECRESCENTE POR IDADE...\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("NOME:\t\t\t%s",info[i].nome);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não pode acessar `info[6]` se `info` é `atleta[6]`, certo? apenas de 0 a 5 existem. Entenda que seu programa trata uma equipe mas só tem atleta. Seria muito mais simples se tivesse uma `struct` com a equipe

Comment: Eu mudei info[6] para info[5] e mesmo assim aparece o erro. Eu ainda estou aprendendo e estou tendo um pouco de dificuldade.

Comment: Esqueça o que eu disse, fucei aqui e ajeitei. Obrigado pela ajuda, deu certo. funcionou como deveria e sem o erro. Ainda estou aprendendo, por isso não peguei o jeito de como me organizar usando o struct, mas logo eu aprendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Escreva em torno dos dados**

Seus dados são 1 time e o time tem atletas. Considere algo assim

```
typedef struct
{
    char  nome[50];
    char  esporte[50];
    int   idade;
    float altura;
} Atleta;
```

sua estrutura de Atleta pode ser anônima. Não precisa do nome `dados` como no programa original. Há uma convenção de reservar alguma propriedade para os nomes que você define, como por exemplo usar a primeira letra em maiúscula apenas nesses casos: `Atleta` então.

E o time? Podia ser

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned limite;
    unsigned tam;
    Atleta   atl[10];
} Time;
```

Algo assim é mais conveniente: cada time tem um vetor para 10 atletas. o Limite então é 10 e o tamanho vai claro de 0 a 10. Assim é mais fácil controlar um time ou 200 times no programa, porque esses valores estão **dentro** da estrutura. É o princípio de encapsulamento.

Algo assim

```
    Time tm = {.limite = 10, .tam = 0};
```

declara um time vazio com capacidade para 10 caras

#### Exemplo

```
int main(void)
{
    char linha[80];
    Time tm = {.limite = 10, .tam = 0};

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("\nDados do atleta %d...\n", i);
        printf("Nome:\t\t");
        fgets(
            tm.atl[i].nome, sizeof(tm.atl[i].nome), stdin);
        printf("Esporte:\t");
        fgets(
            tm.atl[i].esporte, sizeof(tm.atl[i].esporte),
            stdin);
        printf("Idade:\t\t");
        fgets(linha, sizeof(linha), stdin);
        tm.atl[i].idade = atoi(linha);
        printf("Altura:\t\t");
        fgets(linha, sizeof(linha), stdin);
        tm.atl[i].altura = (float)atof(linha);
        tm.tam += 1;
    }
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < tm.tam; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned j = i + 1; j < 5; j++)
        {
            Atleta temp;
            if (tm.atl[i].idade < tm.atl[j].idade)
            {
                temp      = tm.atl[i];
                tm.atl[i] = tm.atl[j];
                tm.atl[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    printf(
        "\n\tTime (%d de %d) em ordem decrescente de "
        "idade...\n",
        tm.tam, tm.limite);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) printf("%s",tm.atl[i].nome);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Saída do exemplo

```
Dados do atleta 1...
Nome:           a1
Esporte:        e1
Idade:          45
Altura:         1

Dados do atleta 2...
Nome:           a2
Esporte:        e2
Idade:          45
Altura:         2

Dados do atleta 3...
Nome:           a3
Esporte:        e3
Idade:          12
Altura:         1

Dados do atleta 4...
Nome:           a4
Esporte:        e4
Idade:          23
Altura:         2

Dados do atleta 5...
Nome:           a5
Esporte:        e5
Idade:          15
Altura:         2

        Time (5 de 10) em ordem decrescente de idade...
a1
a2
a4
a5
a3
```

#### `fgets()`

Cuidado: fgets retorna `char*` e é esse valor que você deve usar nos programas. Se `fgets()` não ler nada retorna `NULL` e a variavel do primeiro argumento permanece inalterada. Isso quer dizer que não vai saber se leu ou não algo e seu programa não vai ter o resultado que você espera... Todo dia milhares de programas de iniciantes entram em loop por causa disso. ;)

Mais: fgets() deixa um '\n' ao final da string, mas apenas se houver espaço. Então você deve testar isso antes de mostrar na tela. A menos que o cara tenha digitado exatos 50 caracteres vai ter um '\n' ao final do nome e do esporte na estrutura

Comment: Obrigado por sua ajuda, foi muito útil, estava com certa dificuldade.

Comment: Bom que ajudou. Marque a resposta como solução assim outros podem ter mais facilidade em encontrar.